# Javascript fetch on wordpress plugins not working

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm using onesignal that sends notifications but the onesignal popup is not showing and it's giving and error. After tracking the error a noticed that the fetch method that is using the api to get the image of the popup from onesignal.

```
const response = await fetch(url);
```

the response is coming as undefined from onesignal but if I try it on different site the api works good. The error message is : `'There was an error showing the OneSignal Slidedown: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'json')'`

but i have the same error when i try to sync the yoast seo

[image]

if anyone can know what is blocking this api.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the developers of the OneSignal plugin yet? If not then it might be a good idea to do so, if anyone can help you figure out what's going on it's them. See [OneSignal Support Forums](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/onesignal-free-web-push-notifications/).

Comment: @cabrerahector Yes I tried contacting their support but I think this is a general problem with some wordpress configuration because is not happening just in the one signal plugins but in other plugins also

Comment: In that case you want to make sure that this isn't being caused by a compatibility issue with one of your plugins. May want to consider using the [Health Check & Troubleshooting](https://wordpress.org/plugins/health-check/) plugin and its [Troubleshooting mode](https://make.wordpress.org/support/handbook/appendix/troubleshooting-using-the-health-check/) to try and find what's causing this issue.